# How to display the same records in one row and other records in the other rows in a report using ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report to develop and I met a situation. For example, I have the following report:

Event info:

```
              provider1           provider2          provider3

              xxx1                xxx2               xxx1
```

My goal is to show the following report:

Event info:

```
              provider1           provider2          provider3

              xxx1                                   xxx1
                                  xxx2
```

I tried using IIF to control it but it will not automatically get to a new line:

`=iif(fields!event_type.value="event info",iif(fields!message.value is nothing,"-",fields!message.value),fields!message.value)`

Comment: Could you show us your sample data? It will help give inputs on your question

Comment: what are the specific conditions to show on a new line?

Comment: @Harry  different content on column message.  if the content of message are the same, show them in the same row. if the content are different, show it in a different row.

Comment: so why not group on the message?

Comment: @Harry because there is other things on message. not only event info. it's pretty complicated.

Comment: that's exactly why we need to see the whole thing to help you..